# VS2017 C++: why is PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES undefined?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winsock2

I'm working with a file that uses the `PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` type. The person who worked on this code was using VS2013 (my current job is to upgrade the codebase to VS2017). The #includes look like this:

```
#include <winsock2.h> // Include for security.h
#include <security.h> // Include for EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT
#include <iphlpapi.h> // Include for PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES
```

And I get `error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES'` when trying to compile. This appears to be a problem in VS2017 but not VS2013.

`PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` appears to be defined in `<IPTypes.h>`, which is included by `<iphlpapi.h>`, but it is inside an `#ifdef _WINSOCK2API_` block. However, this should be defined since I included `<winsock2.h>`. What's going on here?

**Edit:** On second glance, it looks like that error message doesn't indicate that it's undefined, but rather that there is a circular dependency with this identifier. I am continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in my case there was ANOTHER file that had included `<iphlpapi.h>` but not `<winsock2.h>`, which was causing the errors in the file I was working on. For some reason, this file was being compiled first in VS2017 but not in VS2013. Make sure you check all of your includes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to similar problem. When `WinSock2.h` header file is not included, then `PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` is not declared. If `WinSock2.h` is included, then a lot of error messages are generated.

So, thanks to this answer, I investigated the `WinSock2.h` header file and I found this comment:

```
#define _WINSOCKAPI_   /* Prevent inclusion of winsock.h in windows.h */
```

I changed the order of the include files moving `Windows.h` after `WinSock2.h` and `iphlpapi.h` and this solved the issue.